# Java ME Version History

Tags: java-me, version

What is the correct **Java** **M**icro **E**dition version history?

On the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition) and on the [oracle page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/index.html) ain't no specific version explanations.

I need to differ some Java ME books for a library, so I need it as precise as possible with a release date.
I got a book from 2006 and one from 2008 and there are no hints for the version they used.

Comment: All you can say is that the books are based on a version from before they were published, and not a version from after they were published. They may not have used the version that was current by publication date. The 2008 book could even be using a version earlier than the 2006 one (unlikely of course, but you have no way of knowing). I'm not really sure quite what you're trying to establish, or why. Looking at features rather than dates might be more productive?

Comment: @AlexPoole
We try to order all books by their version, so the one who wants to get a book can see in the bookshelf which book covers which version. And since I can't order them by their features, the version number is the most self explainable hint for what is in the book.
For Java SE or EE books it's pretty easy to get the version number. For them I just have to look when the books were released and then check such a table: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)
But I can't find such a table for Java ME.
I hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaME consists of (simplified)

- CLDC - language base system and library
- MIDP - Mobile phone library

The specification of these are the so called JSR (Java Specification Request). There are links on the wikipedia page to the JSRs, and you can see their documentation history. MIDP 2.0 final release was 20 Nov, 2002.

So in 2006, we already had CLDC 1.1 and MIDP 2.0

If you want to tag your books, I suggest to use "MIDP 2.0".

In the base system there was not much added later. MIDP 2.1 is quite similar to MIDP 2.0. There were just additions as additionals JSRs, like for example JSR257 for NFC. I can not remember a phone that used MIDP 3.0, it was definitely later than 2008.